# Where does the \r come from?

Tags: string, bash, perl, expect, carriage-return

I am trying to work around a situation where I need to login to a multitude
of servers without being able to utilize ssh keys. As a result I am
formulating a "that is a bad practice"-expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set arg1 [lindex $argv 0]
spawn ssh $arg1 -l user "hostname; env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c \"echo this is a test\"; echo"
expect " password:"
send "my_supersecret_password\n"
interact
```

Running it works fine:

```
$ ./ssh.expect server
spawn ssh server -l user hostname; env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo this is a test"; echo
user@server's password:
server
this is a test

$
```

But I need a better formatted list when running on more than one system, so I attempt to let perl reformat the data:

```
$ ./ssh.expect server | perl -e '$dump = <>; $dump = <>; chomp($line1 = <>); chomp($line2 = <>); $dump = <>; print "$line1:$line2\n";'
:this is a test
```

The server name is printed as if it ends with a \r. I don't think that it should. Do you agree? How can I get the system to not return to column 0 after printing the server name?

I can verify that both variables contain data by adding a newline to my print:

```
$ ./ssh.expect server | perl -e '$dump = <>; $dump = <>; chomp($line1 = <>); chomp($line2 = <>); $dump = <>; print "$line1\n:$line2\n";'
server
:this is a test
```

EDIT:

As commented, the following works.

```
./ssh.expect server | tr -d '\r' | perl -e '$dump = <>; $dump = <>; chomp($line1 = <>); chomp($line2 = <>); $dump = <>; print "$line1:$line2\n";'
server:this is a test
```

Shouldn't chomp make the tr redundant?

Comment: It usually comes from something windows related. pipe to `tr -d '\r'` before your perl command.

Comment: How silly, that works like a charm! I looked at the output in vim, but set list didn't show the \r, so I didn't even try trimming it.

Comment: `\r` is `^M` in vim but vim is smart enough to understand DOS newline files and hide them (i.e you'll only see them on mixed line-ending files normally).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#History

Comment: As you are already using Perl, why don't you use any of its SSH modules? As it seems you are on a Unix/Linux box, Net::OpenSSH (or Net::OpenSSH::Parallel) may be your best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expect uses a pseudo-TTY to communicate with the command that it spawns, which in this case is the ssh process. TTYs and PTYs by default will translate \n to \r\n (LF to CRLF) in output text. So the output of your expect script would contain CRLF sequences unless you took the effort to remove the CR's. You can see this by running `expect` interactively:

```
$ expect -c 'spawn echo foo; interact' | od -a
0000000    s   p   a   w   n  sp   e   c   h   o  sp   f   o   o  cr  nl
0000020    f   o   o  cr  nl                                            
0000025               ^^--^^--note
```

TTY LF->CRLF conversion is controlled by the TTY "onlcr" flag. I played around with turning that flag off in the expect script but wasn't successful.

Perl's `chomp` command removes sequences of the perl input record separator (the `$/` variable), which will just be \n on Unix systems. In other words, \r isn't special to `chomp` on unix by default. You could alter `$/` in your perl script to make chomp remove the carriage returns, if you like. Or you could pipe the output of your expect script through `tr`, as discussed.

Answer (score 0):

`\r` is used by terminals; the Enter key on your keyboard actually sends `\r` and the Linux kernel translates it to `\n`; `\r\n` is the line ending for output to the terminal and the Linux kernel translates `\n` to it on output.  It's possible to disable those translations, putting the terminal into 'raw mode', in which the program can talk directly to the terminal (see http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/).  This is needed for full-screen programs, such as `vi`, `nethack`, etc.

My guess is that `ssh` is putting the terminal into raw mode on the client (your end) so the kernel on the server end can do the `\n` -> `\r\n` translation on output.  This is what allows you to run `vi` under `ssh`, but it means that when you run `ssh` under a program need to pretend to be a terminal, which means sending `\r` as EOL on output and reading `\r\n` as EOL on input.